# customer_code 'in where clause is not unambiguous?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am a beginner and i am looking for a solution for more than a hour, i don't have time to waste this weekend.

So i want to have the date,destination and name where where klant_code = reis_code but i am getting the error which is displayed in my title. If i use

```
select klant.naam, reis.bestemming from klant,reis where klant_code = reis_code
```

it works, what i don't understand is that it's getting the error only when i want to add the date to the klant(client). What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time and help!
This is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `bestelling` (
  `bestelling_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `klant_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reis_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datum` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Gegevens worden geëxporteerd voor tabel `bestelling`
--

INSERT INTO `bestelling` (`bestelling_code`, `klant_code`, `reis_code`, `datum`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2017-12-12'),
(2, 5, 3, '2018-01-01'),
(3, 2, 5, '2018-03-05'),
(4, 4, 2, '2018-08-08'),
(5, 3, 4, '2018-12-10');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `klant`
--

CREATE TABLE `klant` (
  `klant_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `naam` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `adres` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Gegevens worden geëxporteerd voor tabel `klant`
--

INSERT INTO `klant` (`klant_code`, `naam`, `adres`) VALUES
(1, 'Gester', 'Amsterdam'),
(2, 'Piet', 'Breda'),
(3, 'Klaas', 'Rotterdam'),
(4, 'Henk', 'Etten-leur'),
(5, 'Sjaak', 'Tilburg');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `reis`
--

CREATE TABLE `reis` (
  `reis_code` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `bestemming` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `klasse` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prijs_in_euro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `geannuleerd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Gegevens worden geëxporteerd voor tabel `reis`
--

INSERT INTO `reis` (`reis_code`, `bestemming`, `klasse`, `prijs_in_euro`, `geannuleerd`) VALUES
(1, 'Spanje', 1, 500, 1),
(2, 'Duitsland', 2, 300, 0),
(3, 'Griekenland', 2, 700, 1),
(4, 'Italie', 1, 640, 0),
(5, 'Belgie', 2, 80, 1);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: What's your error sql code?

Comment: column reference `klant_code` in where-clause is not unambiguous. (which means: both tables have a column with that name)

Comment: show us your exact error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issue on your code.

1. use an alias name for table.
2. use `JOIN` instead of `,` comma (`CROSS JOIN`) it's an old style, `JOIN` can let us know each table relationship.
3. SQL statement ensures which column of the data table is clearly marked

You can try this.

```
select k.naam, r.bestemming 
from klant k 
INNER JOIN reis r on k.klant_code = r.reis_code
```

Comment: @user10320039 you can use `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` just ensure that your keys are unique to avoid undesired results. This query should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and time

Comment: I am now trying(for hours) to edit the name with php but it doesn't update. But i will figure it out, or else i will ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Both tables have a column "klant_code".

You have to clearly define it in the where clause, ie klant.klant_code or bestselling.klant_code.

I think you're looking for a join "ON" rather than "WHERE" also.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and time

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with **`Inner Join`** with Alias.

```
select k.naam, r.bestemming from klant k 
INNER JOIN
reis r on 
k.klant_code = r.reis_code
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and time